R function to expand range of numbers/alphabets in a regex
I tried writing a short function that expands brackets [] within a regular expression. Given a regular expression, the function will expand the brackets and return a vector of strings that explicitly spell out each match.
I attempted to account for two cases: 1) a regular expression with a single range (e.g. ^405[0-3L-O]$), 2) a regular expression with multiple ranges where each pattern with the ranges is separated by |. (e.g. ^W3812$|^405[0-3L-O]$|^N17[04][9FK]Z$). I also added additional feature where if show_expanded is set to TRUE, the resulting vector will be a named vector where each name would represent the values in an expanded range.
Below is the code.
#' Regular Expression Bracket Expander
#'
#' Given a regular expression with brackets, expands the expression with explicit matches.
#' Returns a vector of explicit matches.
#'
#' @param rex a regular expression
#' @param show_expanded if set to TRUE, the resulting vector will show each value in the expanded range as names.
#' @examples
#' r <- "^W3812$|^405[0-3L-O]$|^N17[04][9FK][0-3]Z$"
#' regex_expander(r)
regex_expander <- function(rex, show_expanded=TRUE){
  alpha_nums <- c(0:9, letters, LETTERS)
  rex_split <- strsplit(rex, split="\\|")[[1]]
  
  # extract range patterns
  range_pattern <- stringr::str_extract_all(rex_split, "\\[.*?\\]")
  
  # expand range
  expanded_patterns <- lapply(range_pattern, function(rng){
    if(length(rng) == 1){
      grep(rng, alpha_nums, value=TRUE)
    } else if(length(rng) > 1){
      # if more than 1 range, get every possible combination
      expanded <- lapply(rng, function(v) grep(v, alpha_nums, value=TRUE))
      apply(expand.grid(expanded), 1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse=""))
    } else{
      # no range in the pattern
      NULL
    }
  })
  
  # replace ranges with explicit nums/alphabets
  res <- mapply(function(rex, rng, expt){
    if(length(rng) == 1){
      sapply(expt, function(p) gsub(pattern=rng, replacement=p, x=rex, fixed=TRUE),
             USE.NAMES=show_expanded)
    } else if(length(rng) > 1){
      rng <- paste0(rng, collapse="")
      sapply(expt, function(p) gsub(pattern=rng, replacement=p, x=rex, fixed=TRUE),
             USE.NAMES=show_expanded)
    } else{
      warning("The expression ", rex, " does not contain any ranges.")
      rex
    }
  },
  rex_split, range_pattern, expanded_patterns,
  USE.NAMES=FALSE)
  
  # regex with no "|" separator
  if(is.matrix(res)) {
    rnms <- rownames(res)
    res <- as.vector(res)
    names(res) <- rnms
    # return
    res
  }
  
  # otherwise, return
  else unlist(res)
}

I tested with two examples.

single range

r <- "^405[0-3L-O]$"
regex_expander(r, show_expanded=FALSE)
# output
# [1] "^4050$" "^4051$" "^4052$" "^4053$" "^405L$" "^405M$" "^405N$" "^405O$"

regex_expander(r, show_expanded=TRUE)
# output
#        0        1        2        3        L        M        N        O 
# "^4050$" "^4051$" "^4052$" "^4053$" "^405L$" "^405M$" "^405N$" "^405O$" 


multiple ranges separated by |

r <- "^W3812$|^405[0-3L-O]$|^N17[04][9FK][0-3]Z$"
regex_expander(r, show_expanded=FALSE)
# output
# [1] "^W3812$"   "^4050$"    "^4051$"    "^4052$"    "^4053$"    "^405L$"   
# [7] "^405M$"    "^405N$"    "^405O$"    "^N17090Z$" "^N17490Z$" "^N170F0Z$"
# [13] "^N174F0Z$" "^N170K0Z$" "^N174K0Z$" "^N17091Z$" "^N17491Z$" "^N170F1Z$"
# [19] "^N174F1Z$" "^N170K1Z$" "^N174K1Z$" "^N17092Z$" "^N17492Z$" "^N170F2Z$"
# [25] "^N174F2Z$" "^N170K2Z$" "^N174K2Z$" "^N17093Z$" "^N17493Z$" "^N170F3Z$"
# [31] "^N174F3Z$" "^N170K3Z$" "^N174K3Z$"

regex_expander(r, show_expanded=TRUE)
# output
# 0           1           2           3           L           M 
# "^W3812$"    "^4050$"    "^4051$"    "^4052$"    "^4053$"    "^405L$"    "^405M$" 
# N           O         090         490         0F0         4F0         0K0 
# "^405N$"    "^405O$" "^N17090Z$" "^N17490Z$" "^N170F0Z$" "^N174F0Z$" "^N170K0Z$" 
# 4K0         091         491         0F1         4F1         0K1         4K1 
# "^N174K0Z$" "^N17091Z$" "^N17491Z$" "^N170F1Z$" "^N174F1Z$" "^N170K1Z$" "^N174K1Z$" 
# 092         492         0F2         4F2         0K2         4K2         093 
# "^N17092Z$" "^N17492Z$" "^N170F2Z$" "^N174F2Z$" "^N170K2Z$" "^N174K2Z$" "^N17093Z$" 
# 493         0F3         4F3         0K3         4K3 
# "^N17493Z$" "^N170F3Z$" "^N174F3Z$" "^N170K3Z$" "^N174K3Z$" 

I feel like there would be a better way to handle checking for one or multiple ranges. Any suggestions?
Thank you for reviewing and I would appreciate any feedback!
